# How do I make a css style sheet that will replace the computer image with a cat image in the background?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The header is all effed: How do I get this smartcat.png image to be the entire background for the header only?

I am hoping to add the answer to my stylesheet "cat.css" .

I appreciate all suggestions and better practices for coding with bootstrap.

Here is the website:

http://chillcastle.com/cat/felinedelirium

Here is my stylesheet:
    .header-content {background: url("img/smartcat.png");}

```
.header {background: url("img/smartcat.png");}
```

Here is the webpage code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Feline Delirium</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Plugin CSS -->
<link href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="www.chillcreatives.com">
                <span class="sr-only">Poop</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">Felines</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">Cat Tales</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Cat News</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Cat Life</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Cat Stuff</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<header>

    <div class="header-content">
        <div class="header-content-inner">

            <h1 id="homeHeading">Kitty Cats</h1>
            <hr>
            <p>Feline Delirium is a fun thing.</p>
            <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl page-scroll">Find Out More</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<section class="bg-primary" id="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Cats</h2>
                <hr class="light">
                <p class="text-faded">Whoa. Cats.</p>
                <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button">Get Started!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="services">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">BIJOUXXX</h2>
                <hr class="primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-4x fa-diamond text-primary sr-icons"></i>
                    <h3>Sturdy Templates</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">Cats!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-4x fa-paper-plane text-primary sr-icons"></i>
                    <h3>Ready to Ship</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">You can use this theme as is, or you can make changes!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-4x fa-newspaper-o text-primary sr-icons"></i>
                    <h3>Up to Date</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">We update dependencies to keep things fresh.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="service-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-4x fa-heart text-primary sr-icons"></i>
                    <h3>Made with Love</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">You have to make your websites with love these days!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter popup-gallery">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="img/cubecat.png" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/cubecat.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="img/smartcat.png" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/smartcat.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="img/goldencat.png" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/goldencat.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="smokincat.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/smokingcat.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="img/5.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="img/6.jpg" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/6.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<aside class="bg-dark">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="call-to-action">
            <h2>Bijouxxx</h2>
            <a href="Dogs" class="btn btn-default btn-xl sr-button">cats!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>

<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Let's Get In Touch!</h2>
                <hr class="primary">
                <p>Hit us up with your cat pic</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
                <p>123-456-6789</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 text-center">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-3x sr-contact"></i>
                <p><a href="the chill castle @ gmail.com >feedback@startbootstrap.com</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>




<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<!-- Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="js/creative.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aspect ratio of the cat picture compared to the header is way different. You could crop the image in height a little bit to help it fit.

After which you can use this code to get it scale to cover the entire header. You will need to mess around with the css position and the size of the cat image to see what works for you.

```
.header-content { 
  background: url(img/smartcat.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here's the article link for a full width background image - https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Happy coding!

**Added Note**

The header is very thin and currently has an approximate aspect ratio of `7:1`. Which basically means in order to maintain aspect ratio ,every one increase in height will cause a 7 times increase in width. So if you double the height, the width will be 14 (i.e `14:2`)

Now your image on the other hand has an aspect ratio of `25:24`.
So imagine that you're trying to fit a square box inside a thin horizontal line. Not really going to fit without distorting the image.

So you basically have three options.

1. Change `background-size:cover` to `background-size:contain`. This will basically make the height of the image the same as the parent so that the whole image appears without breaking the ratio. Basically it will make sure your whole image is displayed in the container. But this also means that your container will not get fully covered by the image. Here is an example of option 1 . https://i.stack.imgur.com/uimCh.jpg
2. Keep  `background-size:cover` and adjust the aspect ratio of the image to be more like the header. i.e. Crop the image in height.
   Here is an example of a cropped image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsViE.jpg
3. Keep everything the way it is and increase the height of the header to match the image.

Here's a link to show how aspect ratio works. You can toggle the `How to handle ratio mismatches` radio buttons at the bottom to check the difference between options 1 and 2.
http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/  Make sure you have the `show sample image` button checked. Enter the dimensions of the header and either the height or the width of the image to find out what ratio the image should be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help that did something but I think it might be some other part of the over on top of the header that is causing the problem and cutting out the cat with that dumb computer image...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean but I've added a note to my answer that should help you. If it does please go ahead and make this as the answer for others. If you have any questions let me know. Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot Isabel Inc! I will try adjusting the aspect ratio of the image and add another comment as well star the answer.

Comment: Not sure I changed the size of the image and nothing really changed. Is there something to change in the CSS or maybe the less? The header section I am trying to change is 807 x 635 when I inspect the element.

Comment: The width depends on the screen you're looking at so it's really hard to get an exact match. The best way to proceed would be to increase the height of the header a little to allow more of the image to be seen.

Comment: Cool I am trying to override that header completely or just make that entire header invisible? Do you know which file or files I would need to make that change in?

Comment: Looks like the css is coming from a file called creative.min.css you can simply change the padding in header from 0 50 px to `header .header-content {/*Some other rules*/...
    padding: 150px 15px;
}`

Comment: Thanks that file is definitely the one that I need to change... You can see I made some updates to the image and the header but I am noticing that the header is completely opaque and covering the nav bar...as it does in other sections of the site...not so responsive... any suggestions to make the nav bar more visible?

Comment: Maybe add a background to the nav bar or the nav buttons?